# Copy structure to a different structure

Tags: c++, c, memcpy

I was wondering if there was an elegant way to copy a structure to a different structure, where the second structure is essentially the same as the original one, except without the last field(s).

For example,

```
struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
struct B {
    int a;
};

struct A v1;
struct B v2;
```

Would,

```
memcpy(&v2, &v1, sizeof(v2));
```

Achieve the functionality I wish?
Where v2 has the "a" value that was originally found in v1?

Thank you

Comment: Your sample code will read out of bounds. You will need to explain what you want to happen to the "extra" fields in `v1`

Comment: in real life it will work (once you change to sizeof(v2)) I am sure that there all sorts of standards violation though. The better / correct way is to define a union

Comment: What's wrong with `v1.a = v2.a;`? Or, with initialization, `A v1{v2.a};?

Comment: Does `v2.a = v1.a` work [for you]? You can't copy over anything else as `struct B` doesn't have the space/fields

Comment: Use `sizeof(v2)`. Use the smaller struct's size so you don't access out of bounds.

Comment: "*the second structure is essentially the same as the original one, except without the last field(s)*". This doesn't make much sense. Try: `memcpy(&v1, &v2, min(sizeof(v1), sizeof(v2)));` This will work on a wider range of structures, not only the ones in in your example (that most of the proposed solutions rely on). this could be a good candidate for inheritance.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong memcpy. The correct one should've been memcpy(&v2, &v1, sizeof(v2));

Comment: @MitziuEcheverria Edit the question if you need to correct it.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I did.

Comment: @juanchopanza This is a toy example. I am trying to stay away from doing that since the real structures I am dealing with have many more fields.

Comment: In this toy example you should be fine, as both classes are standard layout classes so they both start with an `int`.  In your actual code though it could be different.  If I were you I'd present a more realistic example since there are so many edge cases.

Comment: It looks like UB if `sizeof(v1) < sizeof(v2)`.

Comment: You should probably show real data structures and ask a question about them. C++ and inheritance could fail if logical members `a, b, c` are in different classes on one side of the "assignment", and in one class on the other side of the "assignment". Packing could also affect the "assignment". Also, memcpy'ing bitfields is implementation defined. Also see [is it possible to do memcpy in bits instead of bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17320643/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If instead of copying all bytes in A, you only copy the number of bytes that B expects, you will achieve your desired result:

```
memcpy(&v2, &v1, sizeof(v2)); // remember that the first argument is the destination
```

However, this is not good coding style. With this minimal code example, it is hard to tell, but you would probably want A to inherit from B so that you can convert the two without having to physically copy memory.

Otherwise, this would be easier and cleaner:

```
b2.a = v1.a;
```

Comment: I'm guessing his real application has more than one member in common at the beginning.

Comment: And he's looking for a general solution that handles multiple members.

Comment: Correct. My real application, has quite a few fields which is why I was trying to stay away from copying the fields as you mentioned.

Comment: This would be an interesting application of object slicing if inheritance made sense here.