# Copying a structure to another structure with MFC

Tags: pointers, visual-c++, data-structures, mfc, copy

I have this structure:

```
using SPECIAL_EVENT_S = struct tagSpecialEvent 
{
    COleDateTime    datEvent;
    CString         strEvent;
    CString         strLocation;
    int             iSRREventType;
    int             iSMREventType;
    int             iForeignLanguageGroupMenuID;

    COleDateTime    datEventStartTime;
    COleDateTime    datEventFinishTime;
    BOOL            bEventAllDay;

    BOOL            bSetReminder;
    int             iReminderUnitType;
    int             iReminderInterval;

    int             iImageWidthPercent;
    CString         strImagePath;
    CString         strTextBeforeImage;
    CString         strTextAfterImage;
    CChristianLifeMinistryDefines::VideoConferenceEventType eType;
};
```

And I have instances of this structure as pointers in `CListBox` items. I now have a need to duplicate a structure so that it is a new instance. At the moment I am doing it like this:

```
auto* psThisEvent = static_cast<SPECIAL_EVENT_S*>(m_lbEvents.GetItemDataPtr(iThisEventIndex));
if (psThisEvent == nullptr)
    return;

auto* psNewEvent = new SPECIAL_EVENT_S;
if (psNewEvent == nullptr)
    return;

psNewEvent->bEventAllDay = psThisEvent->bEventAllDay;
psNewEvent->bSetReminder = psThisEvent->bSetReminder;
psNewEvent->datEvent = datNewEvent;
psNewEvent->datEventFinishTime = psThisEvent->datEventFinishTime;
psNewEvent->datEventStartTime = psThisEvent->datEventStartTime;
psNewEvent->eType = psThisEvent->eType;
psNewEvent->iForeignLanguageGroupMenuID = psThisEvent->iForeignLanguageGroupMenuID;
psNewEvent->iImageWidthPercent = psThisEvent->iImageWidthPercent;
psNewEvent->iReminderInterval = psThisEvent->iReminderInterval;
psNewEvent->iReminderUnitType = psThisEvent->iReminderUnitType;
psNewEvent->iSMREventType = psThisEvent->iSMREventType;
psNewEvent->iSRREventType = psThisEvent->iSRREventType;
psNewEvent->strEvent = psThisEvent->strEvent;
psNewEvent->strImagePath = psThisEvent->strImagePath;
psNewEvent->strLocation = psThisEvent->strLocation;
psNewEvent->strTextAfterImage = psThisEvent->strTextAfterImage;
psNewEvent->strTextBeforeImage = psThisEvent->strTextBeforeImage;
```

Is this the right way to go about this? I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52787223/copy-structure-to-a-different-structure) but I am not sure if it is safe to use `memcpy` in this case.

Comment: Just use the implicitly-defined [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I am not sure if it is safe to use memcpy in this case.*

Your doubts are well-founded. The `SPECIAL_EVENT_S` structure has members that are *not* trivially copyable (i.e. cannot be *properly* copied using `memcpy`). For example, it contains several `CString` members – a class with embedded data buffers and pointers; thus if the structure is simply copied memory-to-memory, then destroying one structure (the destination) will potentially cause those data buffers of the `CString` objects in the other structure (the source) to be invalidated. You *must* call the `CString` copy constructor for *each* of those objects. (The same may also be true of the `COleDateTime` member objects.)

As mentioned in the comments, calling the implicitly-defined copy constructor or copy assignment operator for the `SPECIAL_EVENT_S` *should* take care of this; something along the lines of:

```cpp
*psNewEvent = *psThisEvent;
```

But, as you have correctly noted, you will then need to explicitly assign the `datEvent` member *after* that copy constructor/assignment:

```cpp
psNewEvent->datEvent = datNewEvent;
```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try this copy constructor approach.

Comment: I have to remember to call `psNewEvent->datEvent = datNewEvent;` afterwards.

Comment: @Andrew Good point about the `datEvent` member - I included your comment in an edit.

Comment: That's not really invoking the copy-c'tor. That should be `auto* psNewEvent = new SPECIAL_EVENT_S(*psThisEvent );`.

Comment: @AdrianMole My mistake.